# Android web view not working

Tags: android, xml, webview

I am creating a android webview,but when I execute the program it doesn't view the web page.And I have created a xml webview in my application and here my main activity code.
Is my webview effected by java heap limit?

---

// main activity

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url){
 webview.loadUrl(url);
 return true;
 }
 }


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

---

Log cat

```
05-02 03:31:43.270: D/AndroidRuntime(1722): Shutting down VM
05-02 03:31:43.280: W/dalvikvm(1722): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a19ba8)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): Process: com.example.mywebview, PID: 1722
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mywebview/com.example.mywebview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at com.example.mywebview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-02 03:31:43.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1722):     ... 11 more
```

---

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.shopsystem.anything.FirstActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
enter code here
/>
```

Comment: How about the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission?

Comment: what is width height of your PlaceholderFragment, is the webview visible after attaching the fragment ?

Comment: @Raghunandan : Yes.the app crashed.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes I gave the internet permission.

Comment: @udi looks like the webview belongs to the fragment layout post the `fragment_first.xml`

Comment: see that your oncreate 30 line,what your did.post that the 30 line code\

Comment: @sandy oh sorry. I posted the logcat above.

Comment: @prakash Here is my 30th line.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: @udi post your fragment layout pls

Comment: @Raghunandan Sorry! Now I posted my fragment above.

Comment: @udi you initialize webview which is in fragment layout in activity while you infalte the fragment layout in fragment which why you get NPE

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my 30th
>   line.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

This indicates `mWebView` is null. The `WebView` is in `fragment_main.xml`. So you need to initialize `WebView` in `Fragment`

```
public static  class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment{

WebView mWebView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
     mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
     mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
     return rootView;
}
```